# A loop for calculating mean by group and ignore the NA

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, mean

I would like to add a variable new through calculating the mean of a variable old by the group groupID.

```
df <- data.frame('old'=c('20','21',NA,'30','31'), 'groupID'=c(1,1,1,2,2))
```

thanks to some advices from people here, I can ignore NA (na.rm=TRUE) and get the mean of each Group

```
df <- within(df, {new = ave(as.numeric(as.character(old)), groupID, FUN=function(x) mean(x, na.rm=TRUE))})
```

the result loos like this

```
df<-data.frame('old'=c('20','21',NA,'30','31'), 
           'groupID'=c(1,1,1,2,2), 
           'new'=c(20.5,20.5,20.5,30.5,30.5))
```

Now, I would like to further write it into a loop.

the df we have here is:

```
df <- data.frame('old1'=c('20','21',NA,'30','31'),
               'old2'=c('20','21',NA,'30','35'),
               'old3'=c('20','22',NA,'30','31'),
               'old4'=c('20','25',31,NA,'44'),               
               'groupID'=c(1,1,1,2,2))
```

The loop I wrote

```
for (i in 1:4){ old <- paste0("old", i) df[[paste0("new", i)]] <- with(df, ave(as.numeric(as.character(old)),df$groupID, FUN=function(x)mean(x, na.rm = T)))}
```

However, my new variables 'new1-new4' are all full of NaN
Please help me to fix it.

Comment: Not clear why  some values are changed in the expected

Comment: sorry, I am not sure you meaning. which value is changed?

Comment: if you  are calculating the mean by group, why the values are 20, 21, for old1 and old2, should that be the same for grouup 1

Comment: ave(as.numeric(as.character(old)) should reflect old1;old2 etc......

Comment: to split the loop, waht I want to have is: 

df <- within(df, {new1 = ave(as.numeric(as.character(old1)), groupID, FUN=function(x) mean(x, na.rm=TRUE))})  
df <- within(df, {new2 = ave(as.numeric(as.character(old2)), groupID, FUN=function(x) mean(x, na.rm=TRUE))})  
df <- within(df, {new3 = ave(as.numeric(as.character(old3)), groupID, FUN=function(x) mean(x, na.rm=TRUE))})  
df <- within(df, {new4 = ave(as.numeric(as.character(old4)), groupID, FUN=function(x) mean(x, na.rm=TRUE))})

Comment: old1-old4 have been  reflected by this line 
old <- paste0("old", i)

Comment: I think your code is not giving the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to keep your code but did some minor changes within the `for` loop, particularly for the line `old <- paste0("old", i)`. Now I guess what you want might be something like below:

```
for (i in 1:4) {
  old <- eval(parse(text = paste0("df$old", i))) 
  df[[paste0("new", i)]] <- with(df, ave(as.numeric(as.character(old)),df$groupID, FUN=function(x)mean(x, na.rm = T)))
}
```

such that

```
> df
  old1 old2 old3 old4 groupID new1 new2 new3     new4
1   20   20   20   20       1 20.5 20.5 21.0 25.33333
2   21   21   22   25       1 20.5 20.5 21.0 25.33333
3 <NA> <NA> <NA>   31       1 20.5 20.5 21.0 25.33333
4   30   30   30 <NA>       2 30.5 32.5 30.5 44.00000
5   31   35   31   44       2 30.5 32.5 30.5 44.00000
```